# sphinx, django: Link to Django documentation using sphinx.ext.intersphinx

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I would like to add references to django's documentation using `sphinx.ext.intersphinx`. I've tried this:

conf.py

```
....
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    ]

intersphinx_mapping = {
    'django': ('https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/', None),
    'python': ('https://docs.python.org/3.5', None),
    }
```

my docs:

```
:ref:`Model Documentation <django:django-documentation>`
:ref:`Model Documentation <python:comparisons>`
```

Python's work perfectly, however Django's doesn't.

Wondering if some one has achieved this. What would be a better way to link to Django's documentation without using web urls?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a django [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10315) that solved my problem.

```
# conf.py
intersphinx_mapping = {
   'django': ('http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/',
              'http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_objects/'),
    }
```

How ever, it would be nice if someone can add how to cross-reference titles in different docs using sphinx.